# Is DocuSign using up to date TLS cipher suites?

Tags: docusignapi

I have an integration that relies on eventNotification updates, but it hasn't received any updates for a month.

The envelopes are still being created successfully, it just receives no updates.

Coincidentally, a month ago our hosting solution moved to only supporting TLS 1.2 and above. I can see that prior to that change, in successful requests made by docusign, it was also connecting using TLS 1.2

Since then, I can see no connection attempts in the logs, which indicates the requests are being rejected during the TLS handshake.

This can be explained if the two servers trying to communicate don't share a common cipher suite.

The list of cipher suite our servers support are TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

Does docusign not support any of these suites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and is being handled by DocuSign internal ticket CONNECT-1698. Please ask your DocuSign business or support contacts to add you to this bug number.

Currently DocuSign is using some older cipher suites. (I don't have a verified list of the cipher suites at this time.) We're working on upgrading to the latest set.

Comment: can you please revise the question. The question up here was "What TLS ciphers are supported by Docusign?" future readers if this post would come here to find an answer to that one. The user has other problems - the question should reflect that.

Comment: For Developers who integrate on behalf of a client (and don't have a DocuSign account themselves), is there any way to get notified when this critical security bug is fixed?

Comment: I think this answer needs updating - I believe CONNECT-1698 has been resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign only supports TLS 1.1 and  TLS 1.2 at this time.

DocuSign continuously evaluates new industry security standards and ensures that all our services are using the most secure communication. At present time, some newer TLS cyphers that use TLS 1.3 protocol are not yet implemented. We hope to have these updates in the future.

Comment: I have some code that creates an envelope and sets an eventNotifcation on it. This code hasn't been changed and has been working for a few years. Now the envelope is still created successfully in docusign, but the eventNotifcation no longer works. Our logs show no connections from docusign's IP addresses since the our switch to TLS 1.2 and above. The logs wouldn't show anything if the request was rejected in the TLS handshake, which could happen if the two servers don't share a common cipher suite even if both servers supported TLS 1.2.

Comment: The cipher suites our servers currently support are TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

Comment: can you please revise the question. The question up here was "What TLS ciphers are supported by Docusign?" future readers if this post would come here to find an answer to that one. The user has other problems - the question should reflect that.